# Compiler errors in UIKit based framework due to Swift 5.5 concurrency changes

Tags: concurrency, compiler-errors, uikit, ios-frameworks, swift5

I noticed that since Swift 5.5 some UI based classes changed their behavior in how they handle concurrency. I have a specific framework that encapsulates some UIKit features/logic and I am able to build the framework without any warnings, but when I want to use the framework in my app some compiler warnings show up in 'arm64-apple-ios' file. Currently the compiler errors occur in some initializers which have a closure as parameter.

Here is a small excerpt:

```
@_Concurrency.MainActor(unsafe) public init(configurationForConnectingSceneSession: @escaping (UIKit.UIApplication, UIKit.UISceneSession, UIKit.UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UIKit.UISceneConfiguration = { _, connectingSceneSession, _ in
        UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)

        /* COMPILER ERROR 1 -> Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init(name:sessionRole:)' in a synchronous nonisolated context, COMPILER ERROR 2 -> Property 'role' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not be referenced from a non-isolated synchronous context*/

    }, didDiscardSceneSessions: @escaping (UIKit.UIApplication, Swift.Set<UIKit.UISceneSession>) -> Oodin_Base.Executable = { _,_ in NoAction() })
```

Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Comment: This sounds really interesting. Please show real code so we can work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the compile errors by adding the '@MainActor' to my closure.

```
public init(
    configurationForConnectingSceneSession: @MainActor @escaping (UIApplication, UISceneSession, UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration = { _, connectingSceneSession, _ in
        UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    },
    didDiscardSceneSessions: @escaping (UIApplication, Set<UISceneSession>) -> Executable = { _,_ in NoAction() }
)
```